# Subsetting dataframe based on row value

Tags: r

I have the dataset

```
 df <- read.table(text = "  a b c 
                 X Y Z", header = T)
```

and I want to filter based on row value. E.g. keep the column with row value X,Y
but:

```
df[1,] %in% c("X", "Y")
```

returns

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Your columns are converted to factors! use `as.is=TRUE` or `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.table()`

Answer (score 3):

You are close. Use this index of TRUE and FALSE values to subset columns that are TRUE.

```
df[, sapply(df[1, ], as.character) %in% c("X", "Y"), drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: returns an empty dataframe

Comment: @user2963882 please see my edit. You need to coerce all of the columns into character.

Comment: Still got some problem. If I filter only on c("X") it does not return the column name. Just [1] X Levels: X , instead of A X

Comment: @user2963882 That's a common trick. You need to use `drop = FALSE`. See my edit.