# extract column based on row values

Tags: r

Following Data Set:

```
df <- read.table(text = "  a b c 
                 X Y Z", header = T)
```

The command

```
 df[, sapply (df[1, ], as.character) %in% c("Y", "X")]
```

returns

```
  a b
1 X Y
```

but the command

```
df[, sapply (df[1, ], as.character) %in% c("Y")]
```

returns

```
[1] Y
Levels: Y
```

and not

```
   b
1  Y
```

Any idea why? And how I can retrieve the correct column name

Comment: Use `drop=FALSE` in `[.data.frame`, i.e. `df[, sapply (df[1, ], as.character) %in% c("Y"), drop=FALSE]`

Comment: Related, (maybe duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499666/subsetting-datafram-based-on-row-value answered by @RomanLuštrik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generally disable dimension dropping for matrices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196724/generally-disable-dimension-dropping-for-matrices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely a duplicate...but to provide an answer...

You've fallen into one of the major traps of the [R Inferno; 8.1.44](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) where "By default dimensions of arrays are dropped when subscripting makes the dimension length 1. Subscripting with drop=FALSE overrides the default."

So, this will return what you expect:

```
df[, sapply (df[1, ], as.character) %in% c("Y"), drop = FALSE]
```